# How to accept user configuration in a Quire app?

Tags: quire-api

I am looking to create an app, (in my case better described as an *automation*) but would like to allow users to configure the app so it can be used by others than just myself. What is the best way to do this?

The program I have written so far is a NodeJS web server which will subscribe to webhooks from all boards (could do with config options) and hopefully add a certain tag or move tasks to a certain board whenever it needs to.

This is where the issue is: how do I let users choose which tags to add and which boards update?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obviously I can't comment on how you'll have to implement your application front-end for the user.
The quire-api call to add a task to a board, or addTags to a task is both:

[PUT /task/id/{projectId}/{id}](https://quire.io/dev/api/#operation--task-id--projectId---id--put) or [PUT /task/{oid}](https://quire.io/dev/api/#operation--task--oid--put)

In the request payload you can specify a board and tasks to add/remove referenced by their OIDs

e.g.:

```
{
  "addTags": [
    "X6nmx9XjEO2wKbqeB1pRT43C"
  ],
  "removeTags": [
    "mPAQrYU1qt8wAYAInKRlTnvl"
  ],
  "board": "rcBHBYXZSiyDRrHrWPutatfF"
}
```